# How to create a dictionary, using as a keys the frequency of the words?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am writing a script I would like to create a dictionary with some array's words, the array is called removeArray and looks as follows:

```
["RBD", "X", "RBD3", "C", "92173", "GJHGWO.NAYE", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1", "GJHGX4.NAYE", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa", "X3", "GJHGX6.NAYE", "GJHGX8.NAYE", "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2", "GJHGXA.NAYE", "GJHGXC.NAYE"]
```

I extracted that words from a text area, that looks like this:

```
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
```

I would like to create a dictionary that would be composed as the following way, first the keys are the words contained in the array called removeArray, and the value of the dictionary would be the frequency of this word in the textarea, The first key is "RBD" and then it´s frequency is 10, since that word appears 10 times in the textarea.

```
myDictionary = { "RBD" : 10, X: 4, 92173: 6, ...};
```

The first key is "RBD" and then it´s frequency is 10, since that word appears 10 times in the text area.
In order to achieve this, I tried extracting first the words without repetition as follows:

```
var splitWords = document.getElementById("texto").value.split(/[["\|~]/);
splitWords = document.getElementById("texto").value.split(/[["\|~]/)
uniqueWords = _.uniq(splitWords);
console.log(uniqueWords);
var removeArray  = _.remove(uniqueWords, function (word) {return word !== '' && word !== ' ' && word !== '\n'});
```

but then I don't know hot to convert this array into a dictionary with the specifications of above, I would like to appreciate support with this, my complete code look as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="lodash.js"></script> 
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea cols=150 rows=15 id="texto">
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
<script>
var splitWords = document.getElementById("texto").value.split(/[["\|~]/);
splitWords = document.getElementById("texto").value.split(/[["\|~]/)
uniqueWords = _.uniq(splitWords);
console.log(uniqueWords);
var removeArray  = _.remove(uniqueWords, function (word) {return word !== '' && word !== ' ' && word !== '\n'});
console.log(removeArray);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done pretty simply with just `Array.prototype.reduce`. Something like this:

```js
var splitWords = document.getElementById("texto").value.split(/[["\|~]/);

var dict = splitWords.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (p[c] === undefined) {
        p[c] = 1;
    } else {
        p[c]++;
    }
    return p;
},{});

console.log(dict);
```

```html
<textarea cols=150 rows=15 id="texto">
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
```

You loop through all your words and check to see if they already exist in the dictionary. If not, you add it to the dictionary with a count of 1, otherwise you just increment the count.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the support, this was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the dictionary object with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and increment the count with a smart `||` operator use. There is no more need to first make the list unique, as that happens at the same time. Also elimination of empty strings can be done on the fly, like this:

```js
var splitWords = document.getElementById("texto").value.split(/[["\|~]/);
var obj = splitWords.reduce(function (obj, word) {
    word = word.trim();
    if (word.length) {
        obj[word] = (obj[word] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea cols=150 rows=15 id="texto">
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX8.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks this was very useful, I appreciate the support.